# HQL returning associated join, how to do this in Criteria?

Tags: hibernate, hql, criteria

I'm making dynamic query using HQL, but due to many parameters, I believe Criteria would much more "readable". Query looks like this:

```
String queryString = "select u from ReportSalesUnit as r join r.recipients as u where r.id = :reportSalesUnitId";
if ( firstName != null )
{
    queryString += " and lower(u.firstName) like :firstName";
}
if ( lastName != null )
{
    queryString += " and lower(u.lastName) like :lastName";
}
if ( email != null )
{
    queryString += " and lower(u.email) like :email";
}
if ( phoneNr != null )
{
    queryString += " and u.phoneNr like :phoneNr";
}
Query query = session.createQuery( queryString );
if ( firstName != null )
{
    query.setParameter( "firstName", firstName.toLowerCase() + "%" );
}
if ( lastName != null )
{
    query.setParameter( "lastName", lastName.toLowerCase() + "%" );
}
if ( email != null )
{
    query.setParameter( "email", email.toLowerCase() + "%" );
}
if ( phoneNr != null )
{
    query.setParameter( "phoneNr", phoneNr + "%" );
}
query.setParameter( "reportSalesUnitId", reportSalesUnitId );
```

To be honest I have no idea how to return associated join with Criteria. I was looking for answer here, but couldn't find one: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html , could somebody help me? A little explanation would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Criteria can also be used like this:

```
...
if(firstName != null) {   
   criteria.add(Restrictions.and(
      Restrictions.isNotNull("firstName"), Restrictions.eq("firstName", firstName.toLowerCase());
...
```

As it seems, it won't get much more readable with many conditionals. But `Criteria` may help you in this way:

You should pre-check null's (or other exceptionals) before reaching the `Criteria`/`Query` creation. In the end you will have the code like below and I guess it is acceptable for you:

```
... 
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("firstName", firstName.toLowerCase()));
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("phoneNr", phoneNr));
...
criteria.list();
```

And, you can create joins or fetch data via aliases like this:

```
criteria.createAlias("recipients", "recipients", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
```

or

```
criteria.createAlias("recipients", "recipients");
        .setFetchMode("recipients", FetchMode.JOIN);

according to your needs.
```

Comment: Actually that's not what I was asking for. My select looks like this: `select u from ReportSalesUnit as r join r.recipients as u` and I'm wondering how to return associated join (`r.recipients`) with criteria instead of `from ReportSalesUnit as r` which HQL is created for

Comment: Lets say I created criteria like this: `criteria.createCriteria(ReportSalesUnit.class)`, to return asso~ join as I mentioned, I just need to add `criteria.createAlias("recipients", "recipients");
        .setFetchMode("recipients", FetchMode.JOIN);` and simply `criteria.list()`? Or some other way